# sftp login issue with chroot

Tags: centos, sftp, ftp, chroot

I want to be able to create a structure for hosting multiple sites. I want the user files to reside inside /var/www/sites/domain.com and the sftp access to be restricted with chroot.

I've followed some examples on how to set this up, and this is what I've done so far:

Added a new user, set the home directory and group:

`useradd foobar -d /var/www/sites/foobar.com -g sftp`

Inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I've added:

```
Match Group sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and restarted the service

I've configured `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` to include the following changes:

`anonymous_enable=NO`

`local_enable=YES`

`chroot_local_user=YES`

and restarted vsftpd

I've set ownership of /var/www/sites to root and /var/www/sites/foobar.com to foobar

But when I try to connect via sftp using filezilla I get this:

```
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Username and password given to filezilla are correct of course

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you're confusing your SFTP and FTPS. Which do you want to use? SFTP == FTP over SSH (no need for vsftpd), FTPS == FTP over SSL/TLS (no need to touch `sshd_config`)

Comment: not the answer but you don't need vsftpd / shouldn't be running it if you're using SFTP over SSH.  What port do you run SSH on?  Are you running iptables?

Comment: Yes, I got a bit confused. I really just need FTPS, cause I don't want to give user an ssh access, but I'm not sure how would vsftpd know what's the chroot directory without it being specified in sshd_config?

Answer (score 3):

Internal-sftp require chrooted user home to reside inside root-owned dir:

/some/path/root-owned/user-dir1

Root-owned dir should have 555 permissions and user-dirs should be created by root and owned by specific user. Inside subdirs user can do anything, but he can't delete or rename them.

In your case the good approach is the next:

```
/var/www/sites/foobar.com/data
                         /logs
```

User's home is the `/var/www/sites/foobar.com/`

`var`, `www`, `sites` and `foobar.com` should be root-owned. Also `foobar.com` should have 555 permissions. `data` and `logs` subdirs should be owned by user and permissions should be broad enough to allow `httpd` access them.

Comment: I've changed the ownerships and permissions as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that: "Also foobar.com should have 555 permissions." I have lost a lot of time with different configurations that didn't worked.